# Can anyone identify whether or not these are bird or rodent mites?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I found these on my patio furniture directly under a bird's nest that has hatchlings. Surrounding landscape is ivy so we do have raccoons and mice in the area.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7y20.jpg]

Comment: Related: [Bug Identification: Tiny Bugs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/85319/16866), [Tiny white very hard cell bug! Please help to identify!](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/82421/16866)

Comment: As you'll notice from the answers to my linked posts, "`a clear detailed shot is needed to ID this specimen confidently...
In most cases identification of Mesostigmata to family or lower can be accomplished only if the specimen is an adult female.`"