# Can anyone identify this mite?

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

I live in a flat in the UK and have caught such mites a few times on my skin. I think they are responsible for my bites. On one occasion one mite had one dark spot in the middle instead of two.

Does anyone know what it is?[image: mite]

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please [edit] your post to include an estimated size for these creatures. That information can be important for identification. ——— If possible clear, closeup photos of the creature from multiple angles would also be helpful. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Also related: [Tiny white very hard cell bug! Please help to identify!](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/82421/16866)